# Gradle: Set a JVM option on an ANT task

Tags: ant, gradle

I'm using Gradle 2.1 and have an ANT task defined something like this:

```
task myTask {
  doFirst {
    ant.taskdef(name:      'mytask',
                classname: 'com.blah.Blah',
                classpath: configurations.gen.asPath
               )
    ant.mytask(foo: 'bar')
  }
}
```

There is a property I need to pass to the `com.blah.Blah` as a JVM argument (because, instead of doing something sane like passing parameter values in as parameters, the creators of this ANT task have decided that system properties are a reasonable way of conveying information). I've tried a number of things, including:

- Setting the `systemProperty` on all tasks with `JavaForkOptions`:

  ```
  tasks.withType(JavaForkOptions) {
    systemProperty 'myproperty', 'blah'
  }
  ```
- Passing `-Dmyproperty=blah` when I invoke `gradle`.
- Various things involving `ant.systemPropery`, `ant.options.forkOptions`, `ant.forkOptions`, etc. (I can't actually find reliable documentation on this anywhere)

I'm at a loss here. It *feels* like I should be able to say something like:

```
task myTask {
  doFirst {
    ant.taskdef(name:      'mytask',
                classname: 'com.blah.Blah',
                classpath: configurations.gen.asPath
               )
    ant.systemProperty 'myProperty', 'blah'
    ant.mytask(foo: 'bar')
  }
}
```

...but that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Could you perhaps offer some more information regarding this particular ant task? I was able to successfully run a simple test with a task that simply output a given system property via `log(System.getProperty("prop"), Project.MSG_WARN)` when executing my build with `gradle -Dprop=value`.

Comment: @MarkVieira: It's really not relevant. Sure, I could certainly tell people consuming my project to always run `gradle` with `-Dprop=value` flag, but that doesn't address the issue of the build system lacking the ability to specify something in the build system.

Comment: I think perhaps I was confused. You post made it seem as though the `-D` method didn't work. If your only issue is that you don't want to specify a command line argument you can place system properties in a `gradle.properties` file. Just preface them with "systemProp". For example: `systemProp.prop=value`.

Answer (score 4):

In Gradle you can use Groovy so there's nothing preventing you from setting the system property programmatically as shown below:

```
task myTask {
    doFirst {
        System.setProperty('myProperty', 'blah')
        // Use AntBuilder
        System.clearProperty('myProperty')
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that Gradle's AntBuilder executes Ant logic in the same process used for Gradle. Therefore, setting a system property will be available to other tasks in your build. This might have side effects when two tasks use the same system property (depending on the execution order) or if you run your build in parallel.

Instead you might want to change your Ant task to use Ant properties instead to drive your logic (if that's even an option). Ant properties can be set from Gradle as such:

```
task myTask {
    doFirst {
        ant.properties.myProperty = 'blah'
        // Use AntBuilder
    }
}
```